# How can i use useParams() with an onClick button to navigate to different pages and display the data in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url

I'm working on a billing app. I have managed to fetch the Products from an API..... But now I'm trying to use **useParams()** to navigate to random pages that would display the items according to the **ID** by pressing a button...the navigation works fine but it wont display the data of that passed ID, it displays all the data in my API.

I would really appreciate some help or feedback, Thanks !

[image]
[image]

**Item.js:**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getItems } from "../store/actions/itemsActions";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Items.css";

function Items({ getItems, items }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    getItems();
  }, []);


  function getRandomElFromArray(items) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * items);
  }
  

  

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="container">
        <div
          className="image"
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
            height: 200,
            width: 100,
          }}
        >
          <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZlqh.png" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <div
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
          }}
        >
       
          <div className="item-preview">
          
            {items &&
            items.items &&
            items.items.map((item) =>  (
              <div key={item.id}>
                <h4>
                   ID:<Link to={`/bills/${item.id}`}> {item.id}
                  <button className="button4">Analyse Receipt</button>
                  </Link>
                </h4>
              </div>
            ))}
            
      
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    items: state.items,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    getItems: () => dispatch(getItems()),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Items);
```

Billing.js:

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Bill.css";
import { Link, useParams, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getItems } from "../store/actions/itemsActions";






function BillList({ items }) {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(1);
  const { id } = useParams();

  function Display(props) {
    return <label style={{ marginLeft: ".5rem" }}>{props.message}</label>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="bills">
      <div className="explore-container">
        {items &&
        items.items &&
        items.items.filter((item) => item.id === id)
          .map((item) => (
            <div className="item-list" key={item.id}>
              <h2>Title: {item.title}</h2>
              <h4>price: {item.price}</h4>
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
      <div
        className="main-title"
        style={{
          textAlign: "center",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          fontSize: 14,
        }}
      >
        <h1>Bakery</h1>
        <h1>Company Gbr</h1>
        <h1>Oranienburger Straße 120</h1>
        <h1>10119 Berlin</h1>
      </div>

      <div className="bills-container">
        <div></div>

        {/* pass in the details  */}
         <div className="item-list">
          {items &&
            items.items &&
            items.items.map((item) => (
              <React.Fragment key={item.id}>
                <div className="bill-time">
                  <div className="bill">
                    <h4>
                      {" "}
                      <strong>Bill: </strong>
                      {item.billNumber}
                    </h4>
                  </div>

                  <div className="time">
                    <h4>
                      {" "}
                      <strong>Time: </strong>
                      {item.created_datetime}
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                </div>
                ----------------------------------
                ----------------------------------
                ---------------------------------- --------------------
                {/* Counter  */}
                 <div className="price-total">
                  <div className="title">
                    <h3>
                      {" "}
                      <strong>Title: </strong>
                      {item.title}
                    </h3>
                    <div className="counter">
                      <strong>
                        <Display message={counter} />x
                      </strong>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div className="increase">
                    <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}>+</button>
                  </div>
                  <div className="decrease">
                    <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter - 1)}>-</button>
                  </div>

                  {/* Price and total */}

                   <div className="price">
                    <h4>
                      <strong>Price: {parseFloat(item.price)}€</strong>
                    </h4>
                  </div>

                  <div className="total">
                    <h4>Total: {parseFloat(item.price * counter)}€</h4>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </React.Fragment>
            ))}
        </div>  
        {/* <div>
          <h4>     
          Table: Counter
          Terminal: 

         Ust-Id: DE11111111</h4>
        </div> */}
      </div>

      <div className="button-path">
        <Link to="/items">
          <div className="button">
            <button className="main-button">Analyse Receipt</button>
          </div>
        </Link>
      </div>

      <Switch>
        <Route path="/bills/:id" />
      </Switch>

    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    items: state.items,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    getItems: () => dispatch(getItems()),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BillList);
```

Comment: The `Items` component won't have an `id` in the params because its `Route` was not defined to expect one. Only `BillList` will have it. In addition, the `:` is just syntax for a variable part of the URL path in `react-router`, you should not include it in the URL.

Comment: @Brian Thompson  Thank you Brian your comment has helped me understand and fix the problem, but i have another question..... now when i click on the button it will navigate to the right id page but wont display that specific data of the Item ID , it displays all the data......i updated my code and added some pictures for better clarification !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ":" of `path="/bills/:id"` is only used to designate `id` as a route parameter, it isn't meant to be part of any URL. When you link to `` to={`/bills/:${items.id}`} `` you are adding ":" to the id string value.

Remove it from the link. You should also ensure that the `Items` component has `items` to map, where each specific `item` mapped renders the link/button to link to the appropriate bill list page.

```
<Link to={`/bills/${item.id}`}>
  <button className="button4">Analyse Receipt</button>
</Link>
```

The `Items` route also doesn't specify any route params, so there will be be none in the `Items component.

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Items} />
```

Comment: Thanks i removed the ":" from my path, but it still passes the same error "ID:undefined"...sorry i'm kinda new with React.js so it's all very confusing... so i should specify the same path **to={`/bills/${items.id}** in app.js ?  so i can get the data displayed in the billing page ?

Comment: @karimtariq You're not passing any additional props over the route props to the `Items` component. Also in `Items` component you don't appear to map them to `Link` components to then link to the bill list. Can you walk us through what/how you are expecting the UI to behave?

Comment: Yeah sure, i'm expecting the button i click on should redirect me to a URL with the **billing ID** in it and display the data of that passed ID.

Comment: I made some changes according to what you have said……. now its redirecting me to the billing page with the correct ID in the URL. However, it wont display that specific data that was passed by the ID in the URL, it displays all the data…is it because of the mapping ?

Comment: @karimtariq What are the `id`s? In one of your images they look like numbers. The route match params will ***always*** be string types. In order to use `"==="` you need to compare with the same type. Use `(item) => item.id === Number(id))`, or better, use string type `id` properties. It's not recommended, but you could use `"=="` to allow javascript to attempt to coerce the types if you don't have control over the `id` property (*unlikely since you can always augment/update the data*).

Comment: I added this line of code **(item) => item.id == Number(id))** and it worked ..... thank you so much !!